# UK and Schengen Visa rules - order of applying

Tags: uk, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I'm traveling to the UK and Schengen this winter and must apply for both visitor visas. It will be the UK first, then the Schengen area. It will be more convenient for me to apply for the Schengen visa first, but I'm wondering if there's any Schengen visa rule that says I must have my UK visa approved since I'm arriving from there before applying for the Schengen visa? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will want to get your Schengen visa **approved before** you even apply for a UK visa.

The rationale is that, without a Schengen visa, the UK ECO (Entry Clearance Officer) will look at your application and be like :

> How can I be confident they will leave if they don't have a visa for their next destination

Which is a sure path to refusal

Comment: And Schengen doesn't care if you have a visa for your previous destination.

Comment: @StrangerToKindness can you elaborate on your point on why "Schengen doesn't care if you have a visa for your previous destination"? Thank you!

Comment: @cheklapkok Let's say you get a Schengen visa, and then apply for a UK visa. If you get your UK visa, the trip proceeeds as planned. If you don't get a UK visa, the trip collapses and you don't make it to Schengen, and the Schengen visa ends up unused. Either way is fine for Schengen.